# Переклад з російської "подснежник"

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова

Як правильно зробити переклад назви рослини "подснежник" (на фото)?

[image]
В [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов) Вгору](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Подсне́жник, бот. Anemone Hepatica L. – пе́рвістка, ум. перві́сточка.
>   [Розцвіта́є перві́сточка бі́ла (Л. Укр.)]; Hepatica triloba –
>   про́ліска, пере́ліска; Galantus nivalis L. (подснежный колокольчик
>   голубой) – про́ліски (-ків), скоро́ліски, про́серен (-ну), про́серень
>   (-реня);Scilla bifolica L. – ряст (-ту);

Якщо брати латинські назви для пошуку в Вікіпедії (назви з наведеного перекладу з російської мови) маємо різні рослини [Anemone Hepatica L.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) - печіночниця звичайна, [Galantus nivalis L.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)- Підсніжник звичайний, [Scilla bifolia L](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96) - проліски двохлисті

З СУМ-11

> [Пролісок](http://sum.in.ua/s/prolisok)  1, ска, чол., одн. (мн. проліски, ів) (Scilla,
>   L.). Рід трав'янистих рослин родини лілійних з блакитними або синіми,
>   рідше фіолетовими або майже білими квітками на безлистому стеблі.
>
> [Підсніжник](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidsnizhnyk)а, чол. Білий пролісок.

Яке слово варто обрати для перекладу "підсніжник" чи "пролісок"?

Answer (score 1):

На сайті Мова ДНК нації є [картинка](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/pidsnizhnuk-i-prolisok). Якщо подивитися на неї, то стає зрозуміло, що в підсніжника квіти білого кольору, а в проліска - блакитного.

Крім того, якщо вірити Вікіпедії, то [підсніжник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) відноситься до родини Амарилісових, а [пролісок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8) до родини холодкових, тобто це все таки різні рослини.
Однак, тут же читаємо (в статті про підсніжник):

> Інші назви, що трапляються в українській мові: **пролісок**, скоролісок,
>   просерен.

Хоча, якщо заглянемо в [словник Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on), то не зустрінемо там варіанту "підсніжник", натомість:

> **Подсне́жник**, бот. Anemone Hepatica L. – пе́рвістка, ум. перві́сточка. [Розцвіта́є перві́сточка бі́ла (Л. Укр.)]; Hepatica
>   triloba – про́ліска, пере́ліска; Galantus nivalis L. (подснежный
>   колокольчик голубой) – про́ліски (-ків), скоро́ліски, про́серен (-ну),
>   про́серень (-реня); Scilla cernua (пролеска) – про́ліска, про́ліски
>   (-ків), (просирень) про́серен (-ну), про́серень (-реня м. р.); Scilla
>   bifolica L. – ряст (-ту); Primula – перво́цвіт (-ту); Crocus
>   reticulatus L. – бра[и]нду́ші (-шів), бра[и]нду́шки (-шок).

Але, якщо на Вікіпедії прочитати про пролісок, то можна наткнутися на такі рядки:

> Також пролісками в розмовній мові можуть називатися й інші весняні
>   квіти білої, синьої чи блакитної барви — підсніжник звичайний, шафран
>   Гейфеля, зубниця залозиста, фіялка каменелюбна (Viola rupestris) та
>   інші.

Можна зробити висновок, що все ж таки це різні рослини, але в народі як часто плутають між собою. Крім того, слово "підсніжник" є в СУМі (без жодних позначок), тому ми можемо його вживати для перекладу слова "подснежник".

Comment: можливо є ще якісь джерела підтвердження Вашої відповіді, окрім продубльованих  сторінок Вікіпеді та статті з словника, які я надалав в питання

Comment: Якщо ви уважно прочитали статті із Вікіпедії, які я навів у відповіді, то, напевно, побачили, що слова там підтверджуються різними офіційними джерелами, а тому, як на мене, їх можна вважати прийнятними для відповіді.